# VLookup style data structure

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, dictionary, collections

### Problem:

I'm looking for an efficient data structure in VBA, which allows me to lookup a value in one 'column' and find a corresponding value in another column. All columns have the same fixed length.

#### Background

Essentially I have 2 `Enums`, each with *n* items, and an array of *n* strings; I'd like to pass the i<sup>th</sup> value from any of these sets, and return the i<sup>th</sup> value from another specified set

One option would be a `Collection` of `Arrays`; the Collection would have keys corresponding to the type of list (e.g. `Enum1`, `Enum2`, `StringList`), and I would be able to make a function which takes two list keys and a lookup value as argument, and returns the corresponding value in the second column with a loop:

```
Function findCorresponding(dataTable As Collection, header1 As String, header2 As String, lookupVal As Variant) As Variant

Set array1= dataTable(header1) 'pick out array from collection
For i = Lbound(array1) To Ubound(array1) 'loop through to find lookup val
    If array1(i) = lookupVal Then Exit For
Next i
findCorresponding = dataTable(header2)(i) 'return corresponding val
End Function
```

And sure, I *could* replace the lookup arrays with un-Keyed Collections to avoid looping. But that doesn't seem like the most efficient way (I believe `dictionaries` Hash rather than loop, so would be faster on that front, but have a lot of extra baggage compared to an array)

What I really want is something like a `Scripting.Dictionary`, where you can access both `values` and `keys`, and use one to get the other. But with a third parameter that can be found using either of the other two, and can be used to find either of the other two.

If something extends to *n* columns that would also be useful

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, when I have multiple values to store for a key item, I use a `Scripting.Dictionary` and for the value, I just concatenate the values using a `|` (pipe) as a delimiter. Then i can easily use `Split` to retrieve the information I am looking up.

Comment: Sounds like you have a number of ideas - did you try any out which din't work as you wanted?  You say you're looking for an "efficient" approach - do you have specific constraints?

Comment: @braX The advantage of using a Scripting.Dictionary is that if you have 1 piece of information (the key), you can get another (the value) very efficiently. But unlike collections, you can also use the value to find a key (with looping admittedly). I want that for three pieces of information, so that I can use any one to find one of the other two (preferably without looping). Coming back to your example; I can store 3 bits of info in a dictionary, true. But I can't very easily use one of your delimited values to find the corresponding key, or the other value it's attached to.

Comment: Use more than one `Scripting.Dictionary`? It would be simple to create more than one at the same time, right?

Comment: @TimWilliams Efficient = tidy code, no helper functions if I can avoid them. But also fast, as I say, a dictionary lookup is very quick - I envisage a built in data structure which allows me to draw these cross comparisons using more powerful lookup techniques than looping. These lookups will be by far the most frequently called procedure in my project so I'm after an approach which best exploits both the tools available, and the fixed length nature of my data

Comment: There's no built-in structure for this - if you want it "tidy" then you can build your requirements into a class and use that in your main code.